Masking issue in SwiftUI
I'm working on a custom slider using a RoundedRectangle for the track with another Rectangle for the progress with a mask applied. This largely works fine as long as the thumb is not close to the end. As the thumb is dragged close to the right side edge, the RoundedRectangle looks rounded at both ends. How can I fix it such that only the right end of the rounded rectangle shows as rounded ?
struct Slider: View {
    @Binding var progress: CGFloat
    private let stroke: CGFloat = 5.0
    private var thumbWidth: CGFloat { stroke * 2 }
    private var thumbHeight: CGFloat { thumbWidth * 3.5 }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            ZStack {
                Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack {
                    let progressWidth = geometry.size.width * progress
                    let sliderWidth = geometry.size.width - thumbWidth
                    
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: stroke)
                            .frame(height: stroke)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                            .padding(.leading, progressWidth)
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                            .mask(alignment: .leading) {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .frame(width: progressWidth)
                            }
                        
                        Capsule()
                            .fill(.red)
                            .frame(width: thumbWidth, height: thumbHeight)
                            .offset(x: progress * (geometry.size.width - thumbWidth))
                            .gesture(
                                DragGesture()
                                    .onChanged { gesture in
                                        let newProgress = min(max(gesture.location.x / sliderWidth, 0), 1)
                                        progress = newProgress
                                    }
                            )
                    }
                    .frame(height: thumbHeight)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SliderView: View {
    @State private var progress: CGFloat = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
            Slider(progress: $progress)
        }
    }
}

With thumb in the middle:

With thumb close to the end:


Your calculations are a bit off. Try adding .opacity(0.3) to the Capsule and see that the horizontal center of the thumb is not always where the two other rectangles "meet".
I assume you want the horizontal center of the thumb to be where the two other rectangles meet. So you need to add an extra thumbWidth / 2 to their width/padding.
progressWidth should be calculated from sliderWidth not geometry.size.width, because sliderWidth is the total length across which the thumb can move.
let sliderWidth = geometry.size.width - thumbWidth
let progressWidth = sliderWidth * progress

Then add/subtract thumbWidth / 2 where appropriate:
ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: stroke)
        .frame(height: stroke)
        .foregroundStyle(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
        // this rectangle will at least have a width of half the thumb
        .padding(.leading, progressWidth + thumbWidth / 2)
    
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
        // this does not need to be a mask at all - you can just apply .frame to the rectangle directly
        // I'll assume in your real code this is not a simple Rectangle
        .mask(alignment: .leading) {
            Rectangle()
                // this rectangle will at least be half the thumb width away from the leading side
                .frame(width: progressWidth + thumbWidth / 2)
        }
    
    Capsule()
        .fill(.red)
        .frame(width: thumbWidth, height: thumbHeight)
        .offset(x: progressWidth)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    // the actual slider starts at x = thumbWidth / 2, so the x coordinate needs to be shifted here
                    let newProgress = min(max((gesture.location.x - thumbWidth / 2) / sliderWidth, 0), 1)
                    progress = newProgress
                }
        )
}
.frame(height: thumbHeight)


The semi-transparent gray background consumes the width up to the thumb button, then the track consumes the rest of the width.
So an easier way to solve is to combine these two elements in an HStack. This way, a mask is not needed and the issue of the rounding is also resolved.
You might want to add some horizontal padding too, so that the gray zone does not show at the ends. This means, using sliderWidth to calculate progressWidth:
let sliderWidth = geometry.size.width - thumbWidth
let progressWidth = sliderWidth * progress

ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
            .frame(width: progressWidth)

        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: stroke)
            .frame(height: stroke)
            .foregroundStyle(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, thumbWidth / 2)

    Capsule()
        // modifiers as before
}
.frame(height: thumbHeight)


Btw, you might have noticed that the thumb doesn't always return exactly to 0. This can be resolved by adding an .onEnded callback to the DragGesture too. It needs to perform the same update as is being done in .onChanged:
DragGesture()
    .onChanged { gesture in
        let newProgress = min(max(gesture.location.x / sliderWidth, 0), 1)
        progress = newProgress
    }
    .onEnded { gesture in
        let newProgress = min(max(gesture.location.x / sliderWidth, 0), 1)
        progress = newProgress
    }


Here's yet another answer that incorporates suggestions by @Sweeper and @Benzy Neez, with some additional subtleties.
To summarize:

As suggested by others, a mask is not needed since you can simply set the width of the progress bar based on the indicator horizontal location, simplifying logic and layout.
Instead of a ZStack, it uses a single HStack with a Capsule and layered/ordered background modifiers that build the track and the progress bar, for the sake of showing another way of doing it.
Added a tap gesture allowing tapping anywhere on the track to advance the progress.
When dragging the indicator, the grab location should be at the center of the indicator (this is even more apparent the wider the indicator is).
Some minor cosmetic options.
See code comments for additional details.


import SwiftUI

//Slider view
struct CustomSlider: View {
    
    //Parameters
    @Binding var progress: Double
    
    //Constants
    private let stroke: CGFloat = 5.0
    
    //Computer properties
    private var thumbWidth: CGFloat { stroke * 2 }
    private var thumbHeight: CGFloat { thumbWidth * 3.5 }
    
    //State values
    @State private var position: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var maxPosition: CGFloat = 0
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        let dragGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 2)
            .onChanged { gesture in
                position = getPosition(position: gesture.location.x)
            }
            .onEnded { gesture in
                position = getPosition(position: gesture.location.x)
            }
        
        HStack {
            GeometryReader {
                
                //Helper for accessing slider width based on geometry
                let sliderWidth = $0.size.width
                
                //Progress indicator
                Capsule()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(width: thumbWidth, height: thumbHeight)
                    .offset(x: position)
                    .gesture(dragGesture)
                    .onAppear {
                        //Set state for max progress based on slider width and thumb width
                        maxPosition = sliderWidth - thumbWidth
                    }
                    .shadow(radius: 1, x: -1)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: position) {
            getProgress()
        }
        .onChange(of: progress) {
            setProgress(progress)
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture { location in
            //Set the progress to the horizontal coordinate of the tap, accounting for indicator width
            withAnimation(.interactiveSpring) {
                position = location.x - thumbWidth
            }
        }
        .gesture(dragGesture)

        //Progress bar
        .background(alignment: .leading) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: thumbWidth / 2)
                .fill(Color(red: 0.7, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0)) //Darker red
            
            //Logic to ensure the progress bar is not visible when indicator is at zero (since indicator is slightly offset to the right by default)
                .frame(width: position < 1 ? 0 : position + thumbWidth / 2, height: thumbHeight - thumbWidth / 2)
        }
        //Progress track
        .background {
            Capsule()
                .fill(.gray)
                .frame(height: stroke)
        }
        .frame(height: thumbHeight)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    
    //Helper function to get progress accounting for slider bounds
    private func getPosition(position: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        min(max(0, position - (thumbWidth / 2 )), maxPosition)
    }
    
    private func getProgress() {
        progress = position / maxPosition
    }
    
    private func setProgress(_ progress: Double) {
        position = progress * maxPosition
    }
}

//Main view
struct CustomSliderView: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var progress: Double = 0.0
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Progress:")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    Text("\(String(format: "%.0f%%", (progress * 100).rounded()))")
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                }
                CustomSlider(progress: $progress)
            }
        }
    }
}

//Preview
#Preview {
    CustomSliderView()
}


UPDATE:
The progress being passed from parent as float was bugging me since it was really just an offset value. I added a position state and changed the variables accordingly, and made the progress a double that is calculated as a percentage every time the position is changed - and displayed as a progress above the slider.

